# SQL: Reduce query results to single item

Tags: sql

I'm querying an SQL database for an online gaming site. I want to find the game with the oldest user login date (found using min(charstat_last_activated) ) and return the associated unique game identifier (charstat_game). Unfortunately the min function is causing me some problems - whenever I try to create a subquery to return only the charstat_game entry I get an error message.

Below is the code that returns both the oldest game on record and the game id. If somebody can tell me how to adapt this to return only the charstat_game portion from the oldest game then I'd be very grateful.

```
SELECT charstat_game, min( charstat_last_activated ) 
FROM `character_main` 
WHERE charstat_player =11
AND charstat_active =1
AND charstat_game >0
```

Comment: What specific database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery along the following lines

```
select charstat_game from `character_main` where charstat_last_activated = (
SELECT  min( charstat_last_activated ) 
FROM `character_main` 
WHERE charstat_player =11
AND charstat_active =1
AND charstat_game >0
)
and charstat_player =11
AND charstat_active =1
AND charstat_game >0
```

Comment: I like this but I think you need to add the WHERE clause to the outer SELECT as well because otherwise it could return rows that match the minimum `charstat_last_activated` but not the rest of the criteria.  This is assuming more than one game can have the same activated date...